# Dovecot expunge all emails marked as deleted regardless of folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, compression, dovecot, mbox

I have asked the following question elsewhere on StackExchange, and I was pointed here as the best place to ask the question.

The response said that I need to use doveadm which is what I expected. However, I cannot find examples of the correct search criteria. Can anyone help please?

> I would have thought that this would be a FAQ but I haven't found a
> useful answer.
>
> How do I expunge all email messages deleted using the email client
> regardless of which folder it's in?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the MS official article, the only way to delete all email in all folders is to right-click each folder in your folder list, select Delete All, and move the items to the Deleted Items folder.

References: [Delete all email in all folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-all-email-messages-70763b76-f79b-4d03-9840-b20e5f91e393#:%7E:text=Top%20of%20Page-,Delete%20all%20email%20in%20all%20folders,-The%20only%20way).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but my problem isn't in Outlook, it's on the server. When everything is deleted in Outlook, the IMAP  server files do not shrink. I ned to force an expunge for all emails marked as deleted

Comment: Deleting messages Deleted Items folder in Outlook can be synced to the server side. All you need to do is right-click the Deleted Items folder, and then click Empty Folder.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I didn't have to do anything.  By the next morning, the mailbox had resized to empty. Presumably it's an async update on the part of the IMAP server

Comment: Glad your issue has been resolved.